# What are the use cases for application load balancers and Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On ReInvent last week, one of the announcements made was that an ALB can now invoke Lambas to serve HTTPS request. Since we can already connect API Gateway to Lambdas, I'm a bit puzzled as to what problem this new feature solves.

This is the annoncement - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/alb-can-now-invoke-lambda-functions-to-serve-https-requests/

Can someone please give some examples?

Comment: Wow the first time I read the buzzword "serverless application". What an oxymoron. The only serverless applications are the ones that are offline. I can fully understand how those marketing things mixed into something technical are confusing.

Comment: Rather than give an example, I'll ask a question: have you ever configured API Gateway?

Comment: Yes, many many times. I haven´t yet felt "It would have been so great to be able to use an ALB here", and hence my question :-)

Comment: Fair enough. In my experience, anything non-trivial has been painful, with the result that I use a proxy requests rather than leveraging anything API Gateway will do. Given that, and that I'm going to be using a load balancer anyway, eliminating the extra component from my system architecture is a huge win.

Comment: @DanFromGermany applications powered by [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda) are called "serverless" because the servers where they run are not your problem.  Each concurrent function invocation runs in its own independent container, with its own dedicated memory allotment, CPU cycle allowance, and temp space allocation, on servers that AWS patches, maintains, and scales, while billing you only for the capacity you actually used for actually running code, in sub-second increments -- not the amount they make available.  Magic bullet? No.  Mind blowing? Yes.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I understand it after reading about it, but the name makes no sense because there IS still a server handling request and response. The correct wording would be "managed application server" or serverspace or cloud. "serverless" is marketing bs because it sounds fancier and newer than "managed application ...".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem this solves is that it allows yet another way to use Lambda functions to handle HTTP requests and generate responses.

...but you can already do this with either API Gateway or CloudFront's Lambda@Edge feature.

So, what problem does it *really* solve?

Simplified integration of Lambda request handling into server-centric applications that use ALB.

While this feature offers, in some sense, a subset of API Gateway's capability, it differs in an important way --  by allowing you to easily "mount" Lambda functions into a specific set of paths in your existing EC2-based application.

You can pick off specific path patterns and send only those to the Lambda function(s) -- under the same domain without any cross-domain complexity, and without needing to proxy the request through your EC2 instances -- while continuing to serve the rest of the app from EC2.  Avoiding cross-domain resources within an application simplifies many things, not the least of which is cookies and sessions.

While you could also use this in some cases to replace what API Gateway can do, the idea isn't really that you'd set an ALB exclusively for Lambda functions, although of course you could do that.

Comment: Good points, also ALB supports query strings where API Gateway does not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great announcement, truly an enabler for Serverless Architecture. In my view, i feel following use cases are now making more sense:

- Listeners on ALB where port 80 and port 443, now you can route your traffic to different lambda function on basis of port listener. Port 80 will call a different lambda function and port 443 will call different.
- Host based routing
- Application path based routing

now this will enable us to route requests starting with /application triggers Lambda Function.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is that ALB supports HTTP port 80 listeners whereas API Gateway only supports HTTPS port 443.

There are some use cases where the clients / devices sending / receiving data will not support HTTPS for any number of reasons - for example remote or embedded devices.

An ALB now allows potentially cheaper / more targeted proxying directly into a Lambda function rather than routing from CloudFront to API Gateway to Lambda.