# amazon load balancer for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb

I am new to use aws.

Normally, I use load balance like bottom with 2 servers.

[image]

For L4 Load balancing, there are more than 2 servers

But ALB - Lambda is not I think

I am curious about ALB - Lambda relationship

Is it 1:1? not like L4 switch? or VPCs stand for the server?

And I want to know benefit to use ALB for lambda.

Comment: I wonder if [What are the use cases for Application Load Balancers and Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53646044/1695906) addresses your question.  It is not because a Lambda function needs a load balancer.  It's because integrating a Lambda function with an ALB provides a convenient way to expose a Lambda function to the Internet -- either in conjunction with an existing server-based application (you can route specific paths to the Lambda function via the ALB) or as a simpler (easier to configure) alternative to API Gateway (but with fewer features).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Lambda is a short running piece of code (FAAS) - Function as a service. The service executes quickly in milli-seconds and dies out. You need to change the way you are thinking about using Lambda, as this doesn't compare to a VPS(virtual private server) or EC2 instance. You have to go with a different approach, called as serverless computing.

Instead, you can have the API Gateway sit on top of the Lambda functions and you can invoke these API's to execute your code. Each lambda function must do only 1 single task and nothing more.

As a matter of fact, the longer a lambda function runs, the costlier it becomes in terms of billing. So having a short running function is the way to keep your bills in check.

If you want to use lambda - try this serverless-stack tutorial - Ref: https://serverless-stack.com/.

Lambda does have outage issues - and the way to handle this is using Route53 Service as a load balancer.

Another good Reference:
Ref: https://serverless.com/

Comment: I think this answer might be bit misleading. For aws lambda function to be connected from user, it will always need something in front to interfacing with the public Internet user. Having ALB is one of them, and API Gateway is another choice. So both of them are playing similar role, as a reverse proxy of lambda. Only that they have other different function each of them. 
And regarding lambda referred as 'serverless', it actually still need a server to run your code, only you're not the one who manage it,aws does it for you. It takes an IP address and ec2 in the backend to run.

Comment: You say you don't need a LB for Lambda but then you suggest the API Gateway? Potato, slightly different potato.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke lambda via api gateway and alb also. The difference lies in the cost. API gateway is way costlier